# How to await a thread without blocking a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Calling `Thread.Join` waits until the thread has ended, but that means that the thread that is calling `Join` is blocked.

Is it possible, to `await` for a `Thread` to end, but without blocking a thread?

Something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(MyThreadProc);
t.Start();

await t;               // <- ??
// or:
await t.GetAwaiter();   // <- ??
```

Of course, it doesn’t help putting the call to `Join` in a `Task` and await that `Task`, because that would still block a thread.

I’d like to know whether there is functionality in the framework regarding this question that I didn’t find. (Don’t need help on threads/tasks at the moment.)

Comment: Then why use `Thread` in the first place? Use `Task` so you may `await` it.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma Because the threads (there are multiple) do long running IO, disk, database, and network, and with dedicated Threads that’s way easier to control.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blocked"? Await does not block. If you are using a new thread presumably you are doing cpu bound work which will tie up the thread but that is the point. If you are talking about "fire and forget" then just do not await anything (though that makes it hard to handle errors). Also you can start a task, do other work, then await somewhere down down the line.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, `await` does not block. But `Join` does and “consumes” a thread for doing so. That means, the thread can’t do anything else while it is waiting.

Comment: Long-running IO is a perfect candidate for using Tasks with await; you shouldn't need a dedicated thread for operations which mostly result in the thread being blocked waiting for the IO to complete.

Comment: If that can suite your needs - you can callback from your `MyThreadProc` to indicate when thread is finished execution. You can then wait for such completion with await, but it requires cooperation from `MyThreadProc` function.

Comment: You will not find an answer because there is *already* an entire framework part that handles what you want: The Task Parallel Library.

Comment: In the absence of more details, the TPL, as already suggested, has many solutions for you.  However, you can accomplish what you want with a normal Thread using a **polling loop** and some combination of the [ManualResetEvent() Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) and [WaitHandle.WaitOne()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy257t0(v=vs.110).aspx).  No, it's not a "clean" solution...but you're using old-school Threads so don't expect anything better.

Comment: You are looking for TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning

Comment: @Martin If you're not doing CPU bound work at all then you shouldn't be constructing *any* threads at all.  Creating threads just to have them sitting around doing nothing but waiting isn't productive.  Use Tasks that represent that IO bound work instead, rather than creating tasks that represent threads sitting around doing nothing productive.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Those would both be blocking operations, not asynchronous operations, so no, that doesn't do that, that's no different from just using `Join`.